# Why is my variable not holding its value in bash?

Tags: bash

I am horribly perplexed.

I've written a bash script to sort lines into categories based on substrings within that line.

Here's my example "lines.txt"

```
i am line1
i am line2
```

If a line contains "line1", then it should be sorted into group "l1". If it contains "line2", then it should be sorted into group "l2"

The problem is that the variable which holds the category isn't retaining its value, and I have no clue why. Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
categories="l1 l2"

l1="
    line1
"

l2="
    line2
"

# match line1
cat lines.txt | while read fline
do
    cate="no match"

    for c in $categories
    do
        echo "${!c}" | while read location
        do
            if [ ! -z "$location" ] && [[ "$fline" =~ "$location" ]]
            then
                echo "we are selecting category $c"
                cate="$c"
                break
            fi
        done

        if [ "$cate" != "no match" ]
        then
            echo "we found a match"
            break
        fi
    done

    echo "$cate:$fline"
done

exit 0
```

And when I run it, I see the output

```
we are selecting category l1
no match:i am line1
we are selecting category l2
no match:i am line2
```

This means that we are selecting the correct group, but we don't remember it when we exit the nested "while" loop.

Why is my variable not retaining its value, and how could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop is executed in a subshell because of the pipe. That means that the name 'cate' really refers to two different variables. One outside the while loop and the other inside the loop inside the subshell. When the subshell exits that value is lost.

A way to get around this is to use a redirect like this

```
while read line; do
...
done < $myfile
```

If the expression is more complicated and you need something executed in a subshell, then you can use process substitution (Thanks to David Rankin for reminding me about this one).

```
while read -r line; do
...
done < <(find . -iname "*sh")
```

Comment: Why do you still persist using the *here string* and a *command substitution* when only a simple *redirection* to feed the `while` loop is needed? `while read -r line; do ... done < $myfile`. Not `... done <<< $(cat $myfile)` that is a `UUOc` (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*) coupled with an unnecessary *command substitution* as input to an unnecessary *here string*. That is poor scripting and unnecessarily breaks POSIX compliance.

Comment: `"If the expression is more complicated and you need something executed in a subshell, then you..."` use *process substitution*, e.g. `while read -r line; do ... done < <(some process)`. In your example `... done < <(find . -iname "*sh")`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it was just because his initial question used cat, but I've amended my answer to include the redirect.

Comment: Much better. You have to be careful. Otherwise, you (in the role as teacher) will be sending students off with the wrong ideas...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah I agree. Thanks for the help. It's a pity one can't share points from questions answered.

Comment: That's what this site is all about. It's a double benefit. You answer and help someone else while getting tips and critiques on your answer. I have learned a great deal that way.